# Fail2Ban is bannig IPs but they can still attack me what am I doing wrong?

Tags: linux, ssh, fedora, sshd, fail2ban

I'm right now building my first Linux Server using Fedora 36.
I activated ssh and realized that bots are trying to connect to my server.
After a bit of research, I found fail2ban and installed it.
It worked fine, so I thought problem solved, but even after a few tries AND after fail2ban blocks them they are still attacking. I read that they are using persistent connection? Is there a way to counter that or do I have a different problem?

Here is my setup:

> /etc/fail2ban/jail.local

```
[DEFAULT]
banaction = iptables-allports

[sshd]
enabled = true
port = all
filter = sshd
logpath = /var/log/auth.log
maxretry = 3
bantime = -1
```

/var/log/auth.log actually doesn't exist, so I don't know where it gets its data, but it reads something and bans people

> /var/log/fail2ban.log of someone still being able to attack and not being banned after 3 tries

```
2022-08-19 23:40:18,366 fail2ban.server         [2588]: INFO    Reload jail 'sshd'
2022-08-19 23:40:18,367 fail2ban.filter         [2588]: INFO      maxLines: 1
2022-08-19 23:40:18,369 fail2ban.filtersystemd  [2588]: INFO    [sshd] Added journal match for: '_SYSTEMD_UNIT=sshd.service + _COMM=sshd'
2022-08-19 23:40:18,369 fail2ban.filter         [2588]: INFO      maxRetry: 3
2022-08-19 23:40:18,369 fail2ban.filter         [2588]: INFO      findtime: 600
2022-08-19 23:40:18,369 fail2ban.actions        [2588]: INFO      banTime: -1
2022-08-19 23:40:18,369 fail2ban.filter         [2588]: INFO      encoding: UTF-8
2022-08-19 23:40:18,370 fail2ban.server         [2588]: INFO    Jail 'sshd' reloaded
2022-08-19 23:40:18,371 fail2ban.server         [2588]: INFO    Reload finished.
2022-08-19 23:43:07,478 fail2ban.filter         [2588]: INFO    [sshd] Found 79.232.107.204 - 2022-08-19 23:43:07
2022-08-19 23:43:07,480 fail2ban.filter         [2588]: INFO    [sshd] Found 79.232.107.204 - 2022-08-19 23:43:07
2022-08-19 23:43:09,228 fail2ban.filter         [2588]: INFO    [sshd] Found 79.232.107.204 - 2022-08-19 23:43:08
2022-08-19 23:43:09,229 fail2ban.filter         [2588]: INFO    [sshd] Found 79.232.107.204 - 2022-08-19 23:43:08
2022-08-19 23:43:09,350 fail2ban.actions        [2588]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 79.232.107.204
2022-08-19 23:49:04,030 fail2ban.filter         [2588]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.117.78.189 - 2022-08-19 23:49:03
2022-08-19 23:49:04,030 fail2ban.filter         [2588]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.117.78.189 - 2022-08-19 23:49:03
2022-08-19 23:49:04,031 fail2ban.filter         [2588]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.117.78.189 - 2022-08-19 23:49:03
2022-08-19 23:49:04,031 fail2ban.filter         [2588]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.117.78.189 - 2022-08-19 23:49:03
2022-08-19 23:49:04,032 fail2ban.filter         [2588]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.117.78.189 - 2022-08-19 23:49:03
2022-08-19 23:49:04,032 fail2ban.filter         [2588]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.117.78.189 - 2022-08-19 23:49:03
2022-08-19 23:49:04,032 fail2ban.filter         [2588]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.117.78.189 - 2022-08-19 23:49:03
2022-08-19 23:49:04,033 fail2ban.filter         [2588]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.117.78.189 - 2022-08-19 23:49:03
2022-08-19 23:49:04,353 fail2ban.actions        [2588]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 1.117.78.189
2022-08-19 23:49:06,478 fail2ban.filter         [2588]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.117.78.189 - 2022-08-19 23:49:06
2022-08-19 23:49:06,479 fail2ban.filter         [2588]: INFO    [sshd] Found 1.117.78.189 - 2022-08-19 23:49:06
...
```

> iptables -L -nv

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
13336  897K f2b-sshd   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
12829  859K f2b-sshd   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
13026  874K f2b-sshd   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
13170  888K f2b-sshd   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
16162 1358K f2b-sshd   all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain f2b-sshd (5 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  507 38384 REJECT     all  --  *      *       1.117.78.0/24        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       79.232.107.0/24      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       94.131.132.0/24      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       82.65.33.0/24        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       82.157.143.0/24      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       76.186.2.0/24        0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       61.177.173.0/24      0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
...
```

I also set some stuff in

> /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1
```

I also set them to ban the entire network using /24, but I don't remember where I put that.

If someone knows what my problem is or you need more information, please tell me

Thank you

Comment: "_even after a few tries AND after fail2ban blocks them they are still attacking_" I don't see this in the log segment you included. Remember that f2b only blocks for a period of time (search for Ban and Unban entries)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: https://www.linuxcapable.com/how-to-install-fail2ban-with-firewalld-on-fedora-35/

Doesn't fedora use firewalld over iptables? You should use either one of them, don't mix these two.

To make sure, check:
`systemctl status firewalld` and `systemctl is-enabled firewalld`. If it is, reconfigure fail2ban to use firewalld.

Comment: firewalld was active, so I reinstalled fail2ban using the directions from your link. I think the situation has improved, but I still see people trying to connect even if they are already banned, and it still takes more than 3 retries until they are banned.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the `recidive` section in `jail.local`. This handles a much longer scan time (five days in my case), and seems to catch the slow-but-steady attempts I used to see.

Here are my settings; notice it scans the `fail2ban.log` file so it only considers hosts that have been banned.

```
[recidive]

enabled   = true
logpath   = /var/log/fail2ban.log
maxretry  = 3
findtime  = 432000      ; 5 day
bantime   = 2419200     ; 4 week
```

Comment: This didn't really solve my problem, but thanks to bringing the recidive option to my attention, I will implement it anyway.